# Not getting enough power to drive a motor while using MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am a complete newbie at electronics. I was trying to drive a motor using MOSFET. It works well, but the motor does not run as fast as it would run if it were directly connected to the battery. I am using Si2300 MOSFET. Is this supposed to happen? If so, then any suggestion to improve this would be really helpful.
Edit: Here is a schematic-[image]

Comment: Which batter(ies)? 1.5V? 12V? Which motor?  Please click the [Edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/565154/edit) link below your question to add this information.

Comment: (The OP has added a schematic, so the question has been re-opened and the previous now-obsolete comments (i.e. those asking for a schematic) have been deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

Without a schematic it is almost impossible to give a detailed answer. I still want to try. If the MOSFET works as a simple switch you should look in the data sheet for RDS On, if necessary you can connect an equivalent resistor in series and observe what the motor is doing. In general, I would also pay attention to the temperature that arises at the MOSFET. That would be a good indication whether the MOSFET is really fully conducting. A MOSFET that is only partially conductive becomes very hot.

The SI2300 has 20 mΩ RDS on which corresponds roughly to the resistance of a copper line of 1.5 mm<sup>2</sup> and 1.8 m length.

Comment: Don't try. It can't be of any use. Worse, it rewards an OP who has made insufficient effort to post a minimum quality question. Downvoting accordingly. You can delete your answer if you wish. Remember that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

If the motor doesn't run as fast as when you connect it to the battery directly, it means that there is some high resistance problem somewhere in your connections. (I assume you have correctly connected the MOSFET.) The voltage level you applied to the MOSFET's gate seems fine. I would choose a wire with a larger diameter and make sure of soldering the wires as close as possible to the MOSFET.